# electron affinity and measuring open circuit voltage of insulators through rubbing

Tags: insulation, static

I am rubbing two insulators, polyester and teflon on each other. Teflon has more electron affinity than polyester. I need to know exactly how much charge is transfered to teflon and polyester in the process of rubbing and the open circuit voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Way back in freshman physics we used [Faraday's ice pail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_ice_pail_experiment) to measure charges.
You'd have to calibrate it somehow....

As far as the voltage (potential between the two charged objects.) that will depend on how far apart they are.  The potential will change as you move the objects about.  (This is because the charge will be constant, but as you move them the relative capacitance changes and Q = C * V.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is
 [**a better-than-some list of materials and potentials for generating trioboelectric potentials**](http://www.trifield.com/content/tribo-electric-series/)  (potentially).

Polyurethane foam on Teflon looks worth trying!

But eg "box sealing tape" + UHMWPE or PVC is scarily 'good'

Droplets of falling 'machine oil' "splattering off a Teflon surface may be interesting.

---

Their final comment may be worth noting:

- Inaccurate information about air being "positive", etc.-- A triboelectric series table has been circulating on the internet, and it contains various inaccuracies. Though attribution is rarely given, it appears to be mostly from a 1987 book. It lists air as the most positive of all materials, polyurethane as highly negative, and various metals being positive or negative, apparently based on their known chemical electron affinities, rather than on electrostatic experiments. (From actual tests, there is little or no measurable difference in charge affinity between different types of metal, possibly because the fast motion of conduction electrons cancels such differences.) In gaseous form, air is generally unable to impart any charge to or from solids, even at very high pressure or speed.

  If chilled to a solid or liquid, air is expected to be slightly negative, not positive. There are three cases where air can charge matter (in the absence of external high voltage).

  1. If contaminated by dust, high-speed air can charge surfaces, but this charge comes from contact with the dust, not the air. The charge polarity depends on the type of dust.
  2. If air is blown across a wet surface, negative ions are formed due to the evaporation of water. In this case, the wet surface charges positive, so the air becomes negative.
  3. If air is hot (above about 1000°C), it begins emitting ions (both + and -.) This is thermal in nature, not triboelectric.